# Trying to pass argument to dockerfile not working when build an image with .net core app

Tags: docker

I have .NET Core web app and I'm trying to build image using the following command:

```
docker build -f "C:\myapp\Dockerfile" --force-rm -t infoeditor  --label "com.microsoft.created-by=visual-studio" --label "com.microsoft.visual-studio.project-name=InfoEditor.Web" --build-arg USER=MYUSERNAME --build-arg PAT=MYPASS "C:\myapp\InfoEditor"
```

in dockerfile I have:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 AS build

ARG USER
ARG PAT

RUN echo $PAT
RUN echo $USER
```

but echo returns $PAT instead of MYPASSWORD. Also happen to $USER.

What I'm doing wrong ? I put those `ARG` in first line before `FROM` ... same thing

Answer (score 1):

In a multistage build, you need to renew the arguments in each stage:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1 AS base
ARG USER
RUN echo "1) $USER"

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 AS build
ARG USER
RUN echo "2) $USER"
```

And then, to test:

`$ docker build --tag temp --build-arg USER=MYUSERNAME` .

From the [reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#scope):

> An ARG instruction goes out of scope at the end of the build stage
> where it was defined. To use an arg in multiple stages, each stage
> must include the ARG instruction.

Comment: It display "1) $USER" ... Still don;t know why

Comment: It works for me on Linux. Are you running this on Windows? Perhaps `echo %USER%`?

Comment: I'm using docker for windows, yes

Comment: You might need to use `%USER%` instead of `$USER` - I have seen several references to this syntax, like https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/542